# Latex - Bibtex/BibLatex - How can I include a file with space in the path?

Tags: macos, latex, bibtex, biblatex

I am using Mac and

```
\usepackage{natbib}
```

It seems that the space in the path caused problems, i.e. Box Sync.

```
\bibliography{/Users/c082213/Box Sync/AA_My_Papers/MyStats.bib}
```

I have tried to put them in double "", and it doesn't work on Mac. Is there anyway that we can fix this?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

one solution is to use a relative path.
If the .bib and the .tex file are in the same folder you can just write:

```
\bibliography{MyStats}
```

On the other hand, there are many other possible solutions to handle the problem with with spaces in the path. My suggestion is: avoid it to name folders or files with spaces. It will produce problems for some reasons.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with Box and it's default usage of spaces, so I created a soft link having no spaces:
    `ln -s "Box Sync" Boxsync`
then I can use the bibliography command as usual.

Comment: Is there anyway that I can make this automatic. I mean when I reboot my computer. I don't need to type ln -s "Box Sync" Boxsync again. Many thanks

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure about this point since my soft links appear to be permanent.